# Creating a table-like form in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a form that should look like this:

```
Label:         <input field> Explanation of this field
Another Label: <input field> Lengthy explanation, must wrap.
```

I'm trying to do this in Twitter Bootstrap without using an actual `<table>`. A table would prevent the fields from wrapping when on a narrow screen, like a mobile device.

The standard Bootstrap syntax is this:

```
<label>Label name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
<span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
```

Is there any way to get these fields to go horizontal? The class "form-inline" doesn't cut it because the labels don't line up, and the class "form-horizontal" hasn't worked because I can't get the class="help-block" to put the help text on the right.

Maybe there's a trick I'm missing? Or a third-party bit of css to do better forms?

Comment: maybe try help text on [this page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html)

Comment: Tried everything on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, try this (uses Bootstrap classes only) http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/pngWh/11/

(just remove the `.warning`, `.info`, `.error`, `.success` classes to remove the validation states. I left them there so that it would be easier to associate my example with the docs)

This is what it looks like:

[image: bootstrap form validation]

Comment: Thank you. This *almost* works. If the form control isn't <input type='text"> then the help text doesn't line up. Try using a checkbox.

Comment: Your original question didn't specify a checkbox. Can you recreate what you're having a problem with in a jsfiddle, as I did, and share the link so that I can fix it for you?

Comment: I think the right answer is to put a fixed width on the form control. Ultimately, I gave up and added help text using a popover. But your answer does answer the question as asked, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: awesome, thanks - sorry I wasn't able to help with your other issue.

Comment: Hi there, in the jsfiddle the labels are appearing above the inputs as opposed to being just to the left of it? I'm looking for exactly as it is in the image, i.e. the input fields are all aligned and the labels are flush to the right i.e. the last letter of each label is directly below the one above?

Comment: It is not working, as @MarkGargan pointed out. The fiddle does not represent the image here.